# Add multiple images to different HTML data-link-title using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this Javascript here to add images to a website template which is unfortunately locked. That means that i'm not able to change the html code. I only can add CSS codes and Javasript's to the head area.

```
window.onload = function() {
  let soundPacks = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Sound Packs"]');
soundPacks.innerHTML += "<img src='https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/volume-1s-200px.svg' class='sp-logo'/>";
}

window.onload = function() {
      let soundPacks = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Apps"]');
    soundPacks.innerHTML += "<img src='https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/volume-1s-200px.svg' class='sp-logo'/>";
    }

window.onload = function() {
      let soundPacks = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Comments"]');
    soundPacks.innerHTML += "<img src='https://u.jimcdn.com/cms/o/s64e01451c5929131/userlayout/font/volume-1s-200px.svg' class='sp-logo'/>";
    }
```

The Script above adds images to the following three links:

```
<a href="/sound-packs/" data-link-title="Sound Packs">Sound Packs</a>
<a href="/apps/" data-link-title="Apps">Apps</a>
<a href="/comments/" data-link-title="Comments">Comments</a>
```

So far so good. The problem is that the Script only works for one link at a time. What I'm doing wrong here? Maybe this isn't the best solution? Is CSS an option?

Comment: Can you post your entire JavaScript code for adding images, to all four elements? You probably have a typo somewhere.

Comment: `document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Sound Packs"]')` will  always select the first `<a>` tag, you'll have to change it to `document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Apps"]')` to select the other one

Comment: @Kresimir I updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, you just have to put everything into one function. When you define `window.onload` three times, it's the last one that overwrites it.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let soundPacks = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Sound Packs"]');
    soundPacks.innerHTML += "<img src='firstimage.svg' class='sp-logo'/>";

    let animals = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Animals"]');
    animals.innerHTML += "<img src='secondimage.svg' class='sp-logo'/>";

    let zombies = document.querySelector('[data-link-title="Zombies"]');
    zombies.innerHTML += "<img src='thirdimage.svg' class='sp-logo'/>";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-link-title="Sound Packs">Sound Packs</a><br>
<a href="#" data-link-title="Animals">Animals</a><br>
<a href="#" data-link-title="Zombies">Zombies</a><br>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This was exactly what I was looking for :)